# [Android]Cannot get filepath

Tags: android

I don't konw why I cannot get file path.When I choose file,the message will show "Uploading file path:null"How can I fix it?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        filepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" + filepath);

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre>
<code>
            
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
   if (requestCode == PICK_REQUEST_CODE)
   {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
   {
      Uri uri = intent.getData();
      String type = intent.getType();
      LogHelper.i(TAG,"Pick completed: "+ uri + " "+type);
      if (uri != null)
      {
         String path = uri.toString();
         if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://"))
         {
            // Selected file/directory path is below
            path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
         }

      }
   }
   else LogHelper.i(TAG,"Back from pick with cancel status");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

managedQuery has many issues, and its deprecated now. the replacement method is

```
getContentResolver().query()
```

You can find more about this [Here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html).